# How to create generic that extends union type of class programaticaly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have following the code:

```js
const events = {
  a: ['event1' as const, 'event2' as const],
  b: ['event3' as const, 'event4' as const],
};

class SomeClass<
  T extends AnotherClass<typeof events[keyof typeof events][number]>
> {}
```

`T` will be: `T in SomeClass<T extends AnotherClass<"event1" | "event2" | "event3" | "event4">>`

But I would like to see : `T in SomeClass<T extends AnotherClass<"event1" | "event2"> | AnotherClass<"event3" | "event4">>`

Is there better way to accomplish this result other that listing all options like this:

```js
class SomeClass<
  T extends
    | AnotherClass<typeof events.a[number]>
    | AnotherClass<typeof events.b[number]>
> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can map over the properties of `events`:

```
class SomeClass3<
  T extends {
    [K in keyof typeof events]: AnotherClass<typeof events[K][number]>
  }[keyof typeof events]
> {}
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgNzmKEYF4YG8BQMYCGAXDANoDkiyUAjOYWqJFADQyVIoBM9Bj40ALos8MAEYkKVFAGZe-Zmw7UALPJhMhI-MEnKUAVnWbW7aVABsxgVGE4AvgG4cL4ABs+aAIJgQUABZwAE4Awh4QEAA8ACoAfFj2ruFoAMogALZwYZ6RotHwAB5QyAAm3r4BwdkRkVAAngAOcCAAZvCcqKQA1nB1rTD1Tf3mEIKkYACu6WLBgrE4sdiJOO6eMGmZ1RBcufj5cEWlEKL4AD4wPn6Bocm1jc1tIwB0BONTM0FzJzDnl5U3OUGD3a1AgTzEb2ms3miwSSTWGyyyRkuxg+0OYDK2G+pAA0jAAJZgGA9PptIHDDqjEh-a5bO5DR5UvFjSZQz7zfD2bq9foUpmgwQLJZAA)